# Select UserControl from FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, select, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have set up UserControls in a FlowPanelLayout with the help in this question:
[For Each DataTable Add UserControl to FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589810/for-each-datatable-add-usercontrol-to-flowlayoutpanel)

I am now trying to implement a click event which allows me to put a border around the UserControl that has been selected.  I have done this:

```
        private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowlayoutpanelUsers.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;

        // Load and Sort Users DataTable
        DataTable datatableUsers = UserMethods.GetUsers().Tables["Users"];
        datatableUsers.DefaultView.Sort = "Name";
        DataView dataviewUsers = datatableUsers.DefaultView;

        // Loop Through Rows and Add UsersGrid to FlowLayoutPael
        foreach (DataRowView datarowviewUsers in dataviewUsers)
        {
            var UsersGrid = new UsersGrid
            {
                Username = datarowviewUsers["Username"].ToString(),
                User = datarowviewUsers["Name"].ToString(),
                Admin = datarowviewUsers["Administrator"].ToString(),
            };
            flowlayoutpanelUsers.Controls.Add(UsersGrid);
            UsersGrid.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(user_click);
        }
    }

    private UsersGrid selectedUser;

    void user_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedUser != null)
            selectedUser.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        selectedUser = (UsersGrid)sender;
        selectedUser.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }
```

My issue is that it only works when I click in a white space in the UserControl but not when the user clicks on the two labels or image.  How do I make it work for all child objects too?

Also, how can I then use the selected UserControl to do other things like open a form which shows all the details for that selected user?

Comment: I'm guessing UsersGrid is your UserControl?

Comment: @JustinSkiles - Yes it is.  Sorry, I should have explained that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a few suggestions for you.  At the bottom of my response I included code that demonstrates my suggestions.

**Suggestion 1: Fixing MouseClick in your UC**
When you register the MouseClick event for a UserControl (UC) you're doing so for the UserControl itself, not for any controls that you place on the UserControl such as your Labels, etc. If you click one of these child controls the click won't be 'seen' by the underlying UC.

To fix this register the MouseClick event for all your child controls; you can even register the same MouseClick event handler you have for the UserControl itself.

**Suggestion 2: Setting your UC's BorderStyle**
I'd move your code for setting the UC's `BorderStyle` into the UC itself.  Create public property `IsSelected` that's set to true when the UC is selected.  In the property's setter update the UC's `BorderStyle` property depending on the value of the property.

Exposing an `IsSelected` property for your UC can be handy: you can query a group of these UCs to see which ones are selected rather than trying to track this status outside of the control like through a Form-level variable.

*Edit in response to your comment:*
Here's an example of how you might query the UCs in a FlowLayoutPanel to see if any are selected and if one is found how you might take some action.  In this case the action is to call an `EditUser` method that takes as parameters values you get from properties in the selected UC:

```
var selectedUC = flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Cast<UserControl1>().FirstOrDefault(uc => uc.IsSelected);
if (selectedUC != null) {
    // Use the properties of the UC found to be selected as parameters is method EditUser.
    EditUser(selectedUC.Name, selectedUC.Username, selectedUC.Administrator);
}
```

**Suggestion 3: Managing selection in a group of your UCs**
If you want to unselect all UCs in a group except for the one that the user clicks (i.e. selects) you'll need to create an event in your UC that fires when a UC is clicked.  The handler for this event explicitly sets `IsSelected` to false for all UCs in a set (such as in a container type control such as a Form, FlowLayoutPanel, etc.), the MouseClick handler in the UC that was clicked will then set the clicked UC's `IsSelected` to true.

It's worth considering creating *another* UserControl type that manages a group of your UCs.  This new UserControl can encapsulate the code for the creation and state management of sets of your UC and would faciliate using your UCs in other projects as well as keeping the code of Forms hosting your UCs a bit cleaner.

---

I figured that rather than include a series of disjointed code snippets for each of my suggestions I'd include what I'm hoping is the minimum amount of code to allow you to reproduce what I'm talking about.

Create a new Visual Studio Winform project and use the following for class `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        flowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };
        this.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel);
        // Add several sample UCs.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var uc = new UserControl1();
            uc.WasClicked += UsersGrid_WasClicked;
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
    }

    FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel;

    // Event handler for when MouseClick is raised in a UserControl.
    void UsersGrid_WasClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Set IsSelected for all UCs in the FlowLayoutPanel to false. 
        foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel.Controls) {
            if (c is UserControl1) {
                ((UserControl1)c).IsSelected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next add a UserControl to the project.  Keep the name `UserControl1` and add a couple Labels and a PictureBox.  Use this code for class `UserControl1`:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += UsersGrid_Load;
    }

    // Event fires when the MouseClick event fires for the UC or any of its child controls.
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> WasClicked;

    private void UsersGrid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Register the MouseClick event with the UC's surface.
        this.MouseClick += Control_MouseClick;
        // Register MouseClick with all child controls.
        foreach (Control control in Controls) {
            control.MouseClick += Control_MouseClick;
        }
    }

    private void Control_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var wasClicked = WasClicked;
        if (wasClicked != null) {
            WasClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
         // Select this UC on click.
         IsSelected = true;
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set {
            _isSelected = value;
            this.BorderStyle = IsSelected ? BorderStyle.Fixed3D : BorderStyle.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, that is amazing.  It works perfectly.  I just changed some variable names to make it match the standard I have going and set the BoderStyle to FixedSingle.

Comment: Apologies if I am asking too much, but say I want to select a UC and then click a button or double click on it to open up a new form where the user can edit that particular user, how would I go about that?  Basically my plan is that that form will contain the Name, Username and Administrator field and the user could edit that and save it back to the database.  The database read/write I have sorted already so its all about knowing what UC has been selected so it shows the appropriate details on the new form.

Comment: @hshah I edited suggestion #2 with my response.  To do the same sort of thing based on an event monitored by your UC (such as on a click) you can create your own `EventArgs` type (that extends `EventArgs`) that includes properties for the fields in your UC you care about (`Name`, etc).  When you raise this event in your UC you'd populate these fields in your custom `EventArgs` type and read them back in the event handler in your Form.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I landed here looking for some pointers on how to do UC selection in a Container.
Jay's answer works well.

Just one update: The UsersGrid_Load method will only engage the top level controls, children of containers will not participate in the WasClicked event.

```
private void UsersGrid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Register the MouseClick event with the UC's surface.
    this.MouseClick += Control_MouseClick;
    // Register MouseClick with all child controls.
    RegisterMouseEvents(Controls);
}
```

Add recursive method RegisterMouseEvents to the UserControl

```
    private void RegisterMouseEvents(ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            // Subscribe the control to the 
            control.Click += Control_MouseClick;
            if (control.HasChildren) RegisterMouseEvents(control.Controls);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try subscribing to the `GotFocus` event on the UserControl.

Caveat:

> Because this event uses bubbling routing, the element that receives focus might be a child element instead of the element where the event handler is actually attached. Check the Source in the event data to determine the actual element that gained focus.

[UIElement.GotFocus Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx)

**UPDATE**

This question may be appropriate: [Click event for .Net (Windows Forms) user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820490/click-event-for-net-windows-forms-user-control)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a clue what that means or even how to implement it :(

Comment: @hshah, check my edit, there is a link to a question on this site about handling click events with UserControls.

Comment: I did try something like that in the UserControl, but when calling it from the Form it selected each UserControl that was clicked and didn't deselect it when another one was clicked :(

Comment: I tried it again and added a loop in the Form to include all Controls in the UserControl to the click event and got this error: {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' to type 'ContractManagement.Classes.Users.UsersGrid'."}